# How can I have a link on page 2 that opens page 1 and calls a javascript function on page 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, hyperlink

Making changes to a former co-workers code: C#, asp.net MVC, Telerik/Kendo controls.  To simulate tabs/sections on each page, he has a series of links at the top of the page that hide and show sections based on the link selected.  I need to go to a specific section on that page from another page.  How can I call a javascript function on a page from another page?

So the links & tabs work like this:  there are links at the top of the page

```
<a href="/Home/AdminCustomerEdit?compId=315" onclick="GetSec('Locations');">Locations</a>
```

The link is to the same page and the GetSec function displays a div based on the section:

```
function GetSec(id)
{
    "Locations" == id, document.getElementById("DivLocation").style.display = "block"
}
```

I need a link on another page to open the original page and display that section on the original page.  I tried a link on the 2nd page, but it tries to call a javascript function on the 2nd page, not the 1st page.

Summary:

Page 1

Link that calls javascript function GetSec

GetSec displays section "location"

Page 2

Link that opens page 1

Need a way to display section "location" on page 1

Comment: You'd need something that would tell "Page 1" that you've come from "Page 2" and you want to go to that section. There are almost an infinite ways of doing that. One way would be to add a "location" query string to the URL and add the id to that, then have code on "Page 1" that reads the URL, and if the query string is present, shows the associated section.

Answer (score 0):

In page 2 when you click link "Page1" it should route you to Page 1 and invoke the JavaScript GetSec automatically .??

You can do this .. Use a *hiddenfield* in your page to store a value. In your post back after hitting "Page1" link put this in your pagination code.

```
if (CurrentPage != DestinationPage)
{
hiddenfield.Value = "getSec"
}
Else {
hiddenfield.Value = String.Empty
}
```

In your body write onunload="CheckForAnyLookup();"

add

```
function CheckForAnyLookup() {

if ($(hiddenfield).val() == "getSec")
{ 
  GetSec(id);
}

}
```